# I can't save received photo from telegram bot to database like byte array java

Tags: java, telegram-bot

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) { 
    this.responseText = "Kerakli bo'limni tanlang:";

    if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasPhoto()) {
        this.chatId = update.getMessage().getChatId();
        SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();

        List<org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.PhotoSize> photo = update.getMessage().getPhoto();

        GetFile getFile = new GetFile();

        getFile.setFileId(update.getMessage().getPhoto().get(0).getFileId());

        File file = getFileRequest(getFile);

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    }
```

Comment: how can i get photo's data like byte array

Comment: You should not add questions as comments but rather [edit] your post. Also read [ask] and add more context, what exactly you're struggling with (and why).

Answer (score 1):

Please try to get the `file_path` (relative path) first (see [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#file)), and then you can convert the full file path to byte array like

```
  File file = new File(filePath);
  byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
  FileInputStream fis = null;
  try {
      fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      fis.read(bytes);
  } finally {
      if (fis != null) {
          fis.close();
      }
  }
```

or

```
  Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
  byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Comment: Sorry, it was not complete, updated.

Comment: filePath comes null  ------------------- PhotoSize(fileId=AgACAgIAAxkBAAIE5mEnhk-LXquglPxDqfa6cAW9IBRxAAK8tDEbz35BSSFpoAvQPkU2AQADAgADcwADIAQ, fileUniqueId=AQADvLQxG89-QUl4, width=90, height=90, fileSize=1941, filePath=null)

Comment: how can i give request to telegram with file_id for download filepath? With which method  i give request to telegram

Comment: With the [Java Telegram Bot API](https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api) you should be able to get the `File` object with `bot.execute(new GetFile("fileId")).file();`. The full file path would be `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>`.